# passing parameters through react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a code which displays four images and when one image is clicked out of those, it takes up the whole screen.I am using react router to implement the same.
The code is like this
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {FirstPage} from './FirstPage.js';
import {Panorama} from './Panorama.js';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Router,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={FirstPage} />
              <Route path="/image/:id" component={Panorama} />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
        )
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('container'));
```

FirstPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom' ;
import $ from 'jquery' ;
import {Panorama} from './Panorama.js';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

class FirstPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        list:[],
        images:[],
        isClicked:false,
        redirect:true
      }
      this.loadImages=this.loadImages.bind(this);
      this.loadOne=this.loadOne.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('load',this.loadImages);
   }

   loadImages(){ 
      console.log("load");
      var that=this;
      $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'https://demo0813639.mockable.io/getPanos',
        datatype:'jsonp',
        success:function(result){
          var images=that.state.images;
          for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            that.state.images.push({"pano":result[i].pano,"name":result[i].name});
          }
          that.setState({
            images:images
         })
        }

      })
   }

   loadOne(pano){
    this.setState({
      isClicked:true,
      imageUrl:pano
    })
  }

  render(){
    var list=this.state.list;

    return this.state.isClicked?<Redirect to={'/image/${this.state.imageUrl}'}/>:
        <div> {this.state.images.map((result)=>{
        return(<div className="box">
                <div className="label">{result.name}</div>
                  <img src={result.pano} className="image col-md-3" onClick={this.loadOne.bind(this,result.pano)}/>   
              </div>
              )

       })}
       </div>
  }
}

module.exports={
  FirstPage:FirstPage
}
```

Panorama.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Panorama extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return( 
        <div>
        <div className="pano">
              <img id="myImage" src={props.match.params.id} />

           <div className="goback"><Link to="/">Go back</Link></div>
          </div>
        )
    }
  }

module.exports={
  Panorama:Panorama
}
```

With this the URL becomes something like this

> http://localhost:8080/image/$%7Bthis.state.imageUrl%7D

after clicking on an image and nothing comes up on the screen.With this,

> Redirect to={{pathname='/image',params:{this.state.imageUrl}}}

I get syntax errors

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using single quotes instead of back-ticks to produce the string inside your `to` prop.

Try changing

```
<Redirect to={'/image/${this.state.imageUrl}'}/>
```

to:

```
<Redirect to={`/image/${this.state.imageUrl}`}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

are you using `react-router 3` i recommend you to use redirect function provided by `react-router 3`, that is `this.context.router.push()` to start redirect.

sample code in component :

```
class FirstPage extends React.Component{
 constructor(context)
 {
   super(context)
 }
...
}
FirstPage.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

sample redirect action in react-router 3 :

```
this.context.router.push({ pathname: `/image${this.state.imageUrl}`})
```

sample redirect action in react-router 4 :

```
this.context.router.history.push({ pathname: `/image${this.state.imageUrl}`})
```

Comment: No I am using React v4